# Print Function Inside of Apply Function Producing Unexpected Results

Tags: r

Could anyone explain why including a `print()` function within an `apply()` function produces (in my opinion) unexpected results.

Using a toy example, if you were to return a value, the `apply()` function works as expected:

```
apply(matrix(1:8, ncol = 2), 1, function(x) return(1))
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

However, if you attempt to print the same value, here's the result:

```
apply(matrix(1:8, ncol = 2), 1, function(x) print(1))
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

What is going on under the hood that causes the `apply()` function to yield such a result when printing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you would expect the behaviour to be, but from the documentation, `print` prints a value *and* returns it invisibly.  So you're getting the side effect of the printed value as well as the collected results from returning 1 for each row of your matrix.